# Failed to create route route-t: >>> OnException[[com.sample] ->

Tags: apache-camel

I am migrating from camle 2 to camel 3 as below configuration

```
<onException>
    <exception>com.sample</exception>
    <redeliveryPolicy disableRedelivery="true"/>
    <handled>
      <constant>true</constant>
    </handled>
    <log message="got here, before predict, ${exchangeProperty.firstCall}" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
    <choice>
      <when>
        <method>operation</method>
        <bean ref="Procs" method="SampleCommentRequestForError"/>
        <setProperty propertyName="firstCall">
          <constant>false</constant>
        </setProperty>
        <log message="got here, after predict, ${exchangeProperty.firstCallOf}" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
        <to uri="direct:sample-comment"/>
      </when>
    </choice>
    <bean ref="abc_errorhandler" method="abcException"/>
  </onException>
```

and getting below exception :
Failed to create route route-nsm-client-call at: >>> OnException[[com.sample] -> [Log[got here, before predict, ${exchangeProperty.firstCall], Choice[[When[bean{abc}  [From[direct:bbc-call ->... because of Bean language requires bean, beanType, or ref argument

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bean language requires bean, beanType, or ref argument
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: The `<method>operation</method>`is missing a reference to a bean. Example: `<method ref="myBean" method="isGoldCustomer"/>`

Comment: I am using in java                                             @Component("operation")
public class sample implements Predicate {
")                                                                                                                                  
 Still need to add <method ref="myBean" method="isGoldCustomer"/>

Comment: If you have a component (bean) named "operation" being a predicate (with test() method), then you should probably do `<method ref="operation" method="test"/>`

Answer (score 1):

This will work camel 2.x operation but if you try to upgrade camel 3.x for existing code. So, in that case you need to change this code to like below sample  . but rather than  myBean provide whole class package path.

Try below sample code..

for more details, please check below official website..

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/languages/bean-language.html